# Check if file is being copied in python?

Tags: python, copy

I would like to know if a file is being copied or not ?

Here is the situation:  Imagine a python code abc.py checks if there are any files in FRWD directory every 10 seconds. If there are any files, it moves those files into another location. When Someone moves larger files like 1G  or 2G or 10G , abc.py checks for the files in FRWD directory (while they are being copied) and tries to move the files and errors out as the copy is still in process..

Does anyone know any elegant solution for this instead of using try&hit customized pause in seconds?  As of now, I am pausing for 60 seconds before moving each File(if there are set of files)

Thanks and Stay safe

Saira

Comment: Check out Watchdog: https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/

Comment: Do you have control of the process that creates the files in the FRWD directory?

Comment: Please post code you have written so far. You could have a `set` of files currently being copied. Add the filename to the set before you start copying the file, and once `shutil.copy2` returns, remove it. Check the set to make sure the file you are about to copy isn't there.

Comment: A move within a file system should be instantaneous - its just a relink of the file in directory structure. You could create a temporary directory in the FRWD file system and move the files there. That's now the staging area for the real move which could potentially take a long time.

Comment: @JohnGordon   No.. I dont have the control over FRWD directory... that directory is in a shared folder  where anyone at anytime can drop off files  and my Script which is a part of testbed  takes the files and run some set of tests.

Comment: @Mike67 .. Thanks for the link.. Will check it out today

Comment: @GordonAitchJay..  can paste the code snippet